# Return matching object from list of objects of a type

Tags: java, spring, enums

Is there any efficient way of returning matching object of a type based on values in it? Consider following snippet -

I have enum that contains these two Person objects.

```
   public enum PersonEnum {
      Tom(new PersonA("Thomas", 21)),
      Jim(new PersonB("James", 34));
   }
```

In my code when I receive a request, it has a object that contains name and age of a person. Is there any efficient way where I could pass the object to enum, which in turn returns correct enum entry for the person? For example, if input object contains name Thomas and age 21 then I would like to have PersonEnum.Tom returned. Hoping to not do if/else stuff. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe use a hashmap made of up String key name and age and the value the person object ?

Comment: This snippet doesn't make any sense. This is a bad usage of inheritance. PersonA and PersonB should be instances of the Person class with their appropriate instance fields initialized, not classes themselves. If you design it like that, then it's trivial to write a method that returns the appropriate enum based on the name and age parameters.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking a blue print and typed too early. But I am sure you get the point.

Comment: Again I'm not sure why you need an enum there. You can simply have a `Set<Person>` and when your request give you the object, just check if the object is in the `Set`. In fact I don't see which benefits an enum can give you there...

Comment: How do you find correct object in the set that contains certain values? Doesn't make sense to compare each object for values.

Comment: _"it has a object that contains name and age of a person"_ Create a Person instance that have this name and this age and use `Set#contains` to check if its in the set and if yes you can simply return this instance.

Comment: I agree with Alexis C, there is no need for an enum here.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it the follow way:

```
    public enum PersonEnum {


    Tom(new PersonA("Thomas", 21)),
    Jim(new PersonB("James", 34));

    private final Person _person;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private PersonEnum(Person p) {
        _person = p;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return _person;
    }

    //You can name it valueOf which is more verbose
    public static PersonEnum of(Person p) {

        if(p == null){
          return null;
        }            
        //TODO other checks if necessary

        PersonEnum result = null;
        for (PersonEnum e: values()) {
            if (p.equals(e.getPerson())) {
                result = e;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


   }
```

Furthermore that It will be useful to implement *equals* and then *hashcode* for the Person Object. 
I used it in the loop.

Comment: You dont need to cache the return value. There is only one instance of each enum value which is dictated by the JVM.

Comment: My bad I have correct my answer. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: better to call `t.getPerson().equals(p)` to avoid NPE for free

Comment: I suggest to put a guard code (null check or other checks if necessary) at the beginning of the method which avoid NPE that's why I implement that's way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where an enum helps here. You can just have a set of values in your Person class that contains already created instances. Once you get the request, get the age and name parameters and call `exists` to see if this person has been created and you're done.

```
public class Person {

    public static final Set<Person> set = new HashSet<>();

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        set.add(this);
    }

    //equals and hashcode

    public static boolean exists(String name, int age) {
        return set.contains(new Person(name, age));
    }
}
```

If you need a subset of all the person instances you might create, you can populate the set yourself (and remove the `add` call in the constructor), i.e:

```
public static final Set<Person> set = 
           new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Person("Thomas", 21), 
                                       new Person("James", 34)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write if/else stuff anyway, because you need to write a wrapper that will understand that "*take constant field name and age from a class using reflections and try to match it with enum*" for example.

In each Java enum there is a method `valueOf(String s)` which returns you the instance of an enum whose name is the same as provided string. Using it you can get your instance by name only, but there is no other way in Java to prevent if/else (or some reflections mechanizm).

P.S.: in Scala there are case classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need two different classes. But anyway you can do next:

```
enum PersonEnum {

    Tom(new Person("Thomas", 21)),
    Jim(new Person("James", 34));

    private final Person person;

    PersonEnum(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public static PersonEnum valueOf(Person person) {
        for (PersonEnum value : PersonEnum.values()) {
            if (value.person.equals(person)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Make sure you have `equals()` implemented in Person class which compares both age and name. Having `hashCode()` would be useful too. Classic implementation would be

```
public class Person {
    private final String age;
    private final String value;

    public Person(String age, String value) {
        this.age = age;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.age, other.age)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.value, other.value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.age);
        hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.value);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would give this +1 but using something like a Set is better and cleaner than an enum here.